# error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays how to solve

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

Service code which return json data

```
  export class EmployeeServiceService {
      constructor(private _http:Http) { }
      GetEmployees() :Observable<IEmployee[]>{
        debugger;
        return this._http.get("http://localhost:2724/api/employee/1")
        .map((response:Response)=> <IEmployee[]>response.json())
      }
    }
```

In this component class im not able to convert the json data please any one help me to solve my issue

```
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  Employees:IEmployee[];

      constructor( private _EmployeeService: EmployeeServiceService) { 

      }

      ngOnInit() {
       this._EmployeeService
        .GetEmployees().subscribe((employeeData)=> this.Employees = employeeData);
      }

    }
```

html

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let employee of Employees">
    <td>{{employee.Address}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.City}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.EmployeeID}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.FirstName}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.LastName}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="!Employees|| Employees.length== 0">
    <td>No employee to display!!!</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

enter code here

Comment: can you post what is inside console.log(JSON.stringify(this.Employees));

Comment: {"EmployeeID":1,"LastName":"Stein                         ","FirstName":"Nidprxmvtyjnat               ","MiddleInitial":"D","SSN":"122-08-9952","Address":"Ap #461-7976 Enim. Street               ","City":"Rutland         ","State":"VT","Zip":"90400","Phone":"1-796-415-8913","Status":5,"Description":"This is sample data for the Employee Case Study.                                                                                                                                   "}

Comment: see the above is just an object. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs whenever you are trying to bind an Object with ngFor. ngFor directive supports only arrays.

As per the request, it seems it returns only one Object,

```
 return this._http.get("http://localhost:2724/api/employee/1")
```

if you need to bind only one Object no need to use **`ngFor`**.

Also you need to initialize employees with an empty array.

```
Employees:IEmployee[] = [];
```

if you still want to bind one Object to the table, push the Object to the array as follows,

```
this.Employees.push(employeeData);
```

Two options

(i) Change your request to return all employees

```
 return this._http.get("http://localhost:2724/api/employee/all")
```

(ii) Push the Object to an array as follows,

```
ngOnInit() {
       this._EmployeeService
        .GetEmployees().subscribe((employeeData)=> this.Employees.push(employeeData);
      }
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: where to use this code  this.Employees.push(employeeData);

Comment: Inside subscribe

Comment: this._EmployeeService
    .GetEmployees().subscribe((employeeData)=> this.Employees.push(employeeData)); its throwing compile time error

Comment: either change your request to return all employees  return this._http.get("http://localhost:2724/api/employee/all")